# Change value of reactive variable in hook in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have

```
Template.templateName.onCreated(function() {
  this.variableName = new ReactiveVar;
  this.variableName.set(true);
});
```

and in `templateName` I have an `autoform`. I need to set the reactive variable `variableName` to `false` when the `autoform` is submitted.

I have tried

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  myForm: {
    onSuccess: function(operation, result) {
      this.variableName.set(false);
    },
  }
});
```

but it doesn't work since `this.` does not refer to the template `templateName` as it does in helpers and events. It would have worked if I used sessions instead since these are not limited/scoped to specific templates.

What can I do to change the reactive variable in an autoform hook?

I have also tried

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  myForm: {
    onSuccess: function(operation, result) {
      this.template.variableName.set(false);
      this.template.parent.variableName.set(false);
      this.template.parent().variableName.set(false);
      this.template.parentData.variableName.set(false);
      this.template.parentData().variableName.set(false);
      this.template.parentView.variableName.set(false);
      this.template.parentView().variableName.set(false);
    },
  }
});
```

When using `console.log(this.template)` it does print an object. If I use `console.log(this.template.data)` I get

```
Object {id: "myForm", collection: "Meteor.users", type: "update", doc: Object, validation: "submitThenKeyup"…}
```

I use the reactive variable `variableName` to determine whether to either show the editable form or the nice presentation of data for the user. Maybe there is another better way to do this.

Comment: I faced with same scenario but i solved it using `Session` and `autorun`.  And `onDestroyed` of that template i make the `Session` as `null`... Waiting to know any other better way to do solve this... Thumps Up!

Comment: @Jamgreen, is the `Template.templateName.onCreated` and `AutoForm.hooks` codes on the same file?

Comment: Have you tried using `Template.instance().variableName` inside your hook?

Comment: Also `console.log(Template.instance());` prints `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit of onCreated:

```
Template.templateName.onCreated(function() {
  this.variableName = new ReactiveVar(false);
});
```

You may want to add a helper function to grab the Template instance:

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
    getVariableName: function() {
      return Template.instance().variableName.get();
    }
});
```

and then you could potentially call within your form logic

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  myForm: {
    onSuccess: function(operation, result) {
      Template.getVariableName.set(false);
    },
  }
});
```

The MeteorChef has a great article about reactive variables/dictionaries [Reactive Variables](http://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables/#tmc-reactive-variables).

Answer (score 1):

If people stumble upon this for a solution, based [this thread](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/433) I as able to access the parents Reactive Dict/Reactive Variable after installing [aldeed:template-extension](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension) like so

```
AutoForm.hooks({                                                                                                                         
  postFormId: {
    //onSuccess hook of my post form
    onSuccess: function(formType, result) {
      this.template.parent().reactiveDictVariable.set('imgId', 'newValueSetOnSuccess');
      //Or reactive var, and depending on your hierarchy
      //this.template.parent().parent().yourReactiveVar.set(undefined);
    }   
  }
});
```

Here is Html and JS for reference.

```
<template name="postsTemplate"> 
  {{#autoForm schema=postFormSchema id="postFormId" type="method" meteormethod="addPost"}}
   <!-- other autoform stuff -->
   This is reactive variable used in template -- {{imgId}}
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>


Template.postsTemplate.created = function() { 
  //Using reactive-dict package here                                                                                                   
  this.reactiveDictVariable = new ReactiveDict();
  this.reactiveDictVariable.set('imgId', undefined);
};

Template.posts.events(
  "change .some-class": function(event, template) {
   //other stuff
   template.postImgState.set('imgId', 'something');
}
```